# Recursively removing fields of type `never` from a type in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

In TypeScript, if an object type contains a field whose type is `never`, you can't really instantiate an object of the type. Example:

```
type x = { a: string; b: never };
const xx: x = { a: "asd" }; // property 'b' is missing
```

I figured it might be useful (actually I mostly thought it would be a fun challenge) to be able to remove all fields that cannot be assigned to, and my solution is:

```
/** Recursively decays all fields that are of type `never` from `T`.
 * @example DecayNever<number> // yields number
 * @example DecayNever<{ x: number; y: string; z: never }> // yields { x: number; y: string }
 * @example DecayNever<{ x: number; y: { z: never } }> // yields { x: number }
 * @example DecayNever<{ x: number; y: { z: never, w: string } }> // yields { x: number, y: { w: string } }
 * @example DecayNever<{ a: { b: { c: never } } }> // yields never
 */
export type DecayNever<T> = T extends Record<string | number | symbol, unknown>
    ? FilteredKeys<{ [K in keyof T]: DecayNever<T[K]> }> extends never
        ? never
        : Pick<DecayNeverType<T>, FilteredKeys<DecayNeverType<T>>>
    : T;

type DecayNeverType<T> = { [K in keyof T]: DecayNever<T[K]> };

/** Returns a union of all keys of `T` where `T[K]` is not `never` */
type FilteredKeys<T> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends never ? never : K }[keyof T];

type t_1 = DecayNever<number>;
type t_2 = DecayNever<{ x: number; y: string; z: never }>;
type t_3 = DecayNever<{ x: number; y: { z: never } }>;
type t_4 = DecayNever<{ x: number; y: { z: never, w: string } }>;
type t_5 = DecayNever<{ a: { b: { c: never } } }>;
```

[playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=12&ssc=9&pln=8&pc=1#code/PQKhAICUFMGMFcBOBnAlgN2gGwJ7gCZwCGOy4RWW4AZqtvmQC4AWRj5i04A9teIzgAOXAAYA7aJkQiaibgFtwIgCoiAdAFgAUOAgABaAA8i8wVi4ARYjgByk6IgA8Y+PIBGDgHzhgwcDjosBnAXdwdtXXADY1NzcCtYEjspRwBvcEMALhDXD0QAbn9s5EZEVDEAc0KAL2yJKXAAX29ff0Dg9KycsIKi8BKyyqaI-SMTM0trZIc0jLrch0KcbPTakPtEJqaWvwD6Mk75nuGdUZiJ+KmN2a7QvKWV8DX6hwAacAB3YtLyiq3mny7doHObdPLvZbgdJffo-IaNE6RaLjOIJJLXdJER5uR6wOobf7bQFtfbrKQjYDaIyCbiIdgCYSXRK2a7KbwAXnAynARkY0DEwRgsFp+EcA1+4AAPmCHFL+jh3NwsO94GIANZibgfMSebQASAA-OAAGKoLB8zj4ADS0FIswA2lbwOVwGrbbwuQBdbJolkpZSOz3eAG8-nBF6IfWGsnhLR6vXZAAKqFgascvumiGUQmgjjZ71N5oc0GttuQ6auUmzwjznjr+uyyny2m0DMmzMz1dzbPAnPSjudYld7r4ym9TPR-sDwebWm0oAgMEYSDEZCI4FVqG4Q49FCobtIPD4KhkH2YxaUAatnpkqDImvY4g2MhAlK0bZNZotJZtdp7ffAAcXQPD0x0bQMeUMPkBXvAkjQjcBsidRp7RA0dPVnVsc34AB9ABGXsJz9GY7i8WcP0YHCACZCIzDFQVI3pIXFSoanxBpmnI7DKIAZloysZkOGUmMeZ4CQRTisMZSiABZ+I7ejbgWESoSedi3k+b5Bj+CTPC46ScIAVnkydBPIbFcXUzYJO2WcgA)

This does seems to work, though it is very, well, wonky. I'm surprised there isn't a built-in method to do this, but is there a better way to do this? It feels very inelegant, and the check to ensure `FilteredKeys<...>` is not `never` is because `Pick<T, never>` results in the `{}` type (which I think is somewhat similar to `any`?).

Comment: Even in 2022, with all our advancements in TypeScript, this looks very clean to me. The one change I'd do for brevity is `string | number | symbol` => `any` or `PropertyKey`.